# $.when produces different result when $.ajax are inline vs $.ajax are returned by a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, .when

Using jquery 1.12 I need to wait for the results of two AJAX calls before I go any further. When I used `$.when` I don't understand why I don't get the same results when I pass the `$.ajax` directly and when I return a `$.ajax` from a function call.

This works. In the `done` part `func1` is an array, with `func1[0]` being the data returned:

```
$.when($.ajax({
  url: url1,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
  },
  success: function (data){
    debugger;
  } 
}), $.ajax(...)
).done(function(func1, func2) {
  debugger;
})
```

This does not. In the `done` part `func1` is `undefined`:

```
var myfunc = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true  
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    success: function (data) {
      debugger;
    }   
  });
}

$.when(myfunc(), $.ajax(...)).done(function(func1, func2) {
  debugger;
})
```

In the second case I just wrapped the first ajax call into a function.

**EDITED**

Probleme Solved. I wrote

```
return 
 $.ajax({
  url: url1,...
```

instead of

```
return $.ajax({
  url: url1,...
```

In the first case, the parser interprets the instruction as two instructions : return undefined then $.ajax. The $.ajax instruction is never executed because we already exited the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `func1` is undefined, perhaps `myfunc()` is not returning anything? Should you not pass `myfunc` as a function name instead of a function call, e.g. `$.when(myfunc, $.ajax())`...?

Comment: You were right. I wrote "return<carriage return>$.ajax(...)" which returned nothing.